# Algorithm running time

Tags: c++, algorithm, code-analysis, analysis

What would the running time be? I got O(n^2)

```
`cin >> n;
 min = 2*n;
 max = (n+3)*10;

for(int i=0; i<1000; i++)
    for(int j =0; j<n; j++)
         for(int k = min; k< max;k++)
            p = f+c+m
```

`

Answer (score 1):

No matter what outer loop runs 1000 times..so the complexity ~`O(n^2)`.
[innermost runs `10n+30-2n = 8n+30` times and loop with variable `j` runs `n` times..]

Answer (score 1):

The number of times `p` is computed is:

```
   1000 * n * (max - min)
=  1000 * n * ((n + 3)*10 - 2*n)
=  1000 * n * (10*n + 30 - 2*n)
=  1000 * n * (8*n + 30)
=  8000 * n^2 + 30000 * n
```

Yes, it is O(n^2).